# Як перекласти українською російський вираз "тут как тут"

Tags: переклад, from-russian

Російська має вираз "тут как тут", що означає, що щось чи хтось з'явився в певному місці саме в потрібний момент.

Як приклад [в рос. словнику](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%82%D1%83%D1%82_%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA_%D1%82%D1%83%D1%82) наводиться фрагмент вірша Лермонтова:

```
Чуть утро осветило пушки 
И леса синие верхушки
Французы тут как тут
```

Що в перекладі українською (єдиному який я знайшов) передається одним словом `тут`:

```
Ледь заблищало вранці знову
й осяяло лісні покрови –
а вже й французи тут.
```

Чи є сталий вираз в українській мові із відповідним значенням?

Comment: `Незабарився` .

Comment: @Gluttton, підтримую, але пишеться окремо («не забарився»).

Comment: @Sasha це ж могло бути навмисним поєднанням задля досягнення ефекта вигуку.

Answer (score 11):

[Російсько-український словник сталих виразів онлайн](http://stalivyrazy.org.ua/index2.php) пропонує такі варіанти:

> **Тут как тут** (разг.).
>
> ***`Тут і (тут як) уродився, уродилася, уродилося`***; ***`як тут`***; (*іноді*) ***`сусіль`***.

Підтвердження першому варіанту знаходимо в СУМ.

[УРОДЖУВАТИСЯ (ВРОДЖУВАТИСЯ)](http://sum.in.ua/s/urodzhuvatysja), оджуюся, оджуєшся, недок., рідко, УРОДИТИСЯ (ВРОДИТИСЯ), оджуся, одишся, док.

> ♦ **Так і уродився**; **Тут і уродився**; **Як (немов) уродився** —
>   ***з'явився раптово, несподівано***. *«І чому хоч Прокіп не прийшов вечеряти!» — думаю. Коли він так і вродився перед очима моїми!* (Марко
>   Вовчок, I, 1955, 127); *Аж ось і пан наш раптом немов уродився перед
>   нами* (Іван Франко, II, 1950, 53); *На рундуці коло крамниці, як
>   уродився, дід Маркіян; розмахує руками, щось доводить людям* (Степан
>   Васильченко, II, 1959, 185); **Уроджуватися (уродитися) там, де [і] не
>   сіяли** див. сіяти; **Як (наче, немов і т. ін.) уродитися з-під (з)
>   землі** див. земля.

Варті уваги також два додаткових варіанти, наведені в СУМ.

[СІ́ЯТИ](http://sum.in.ua/s/sijaty), сію, сієш, недок.

> **Уроджуватися (уродитися) там, де [і] не сіяли** — ***з'являтися там, куди не запрошували, де не чекали.*** *Він вроджувався й там, де його
>   не сіяли, і підбивав хліборобів або палити панів, або скіпати з них
>   лучину* (Михайло Стельмах, I, 1962, 614); *Кореспонденти — це такі
>   люди, що можуть вродитися навіть там, де їх і не сіяли* (Вадим Собко,
>   Біле полум'я, 1952, 156).

[ЗЕМЛЯ́](http://sum.in.ua/s/zemlja), і, жін

> **Як (наче, немов і т. ін.) вирости (виринути, уродитися і т. ін.) з-під (з) землі** — ***раптово, несподівано з'явитися.*** *Враз біля
>   нас як з-під землі виріс стражник Чапля* (Петро Панч, Гарні хлопці,
>   1959, 32); *Всі три хлопці з'явилися, як би з-під землі виринули*
>   (Лесь Мартович, Тв., 1954, 148); *Скрізь по полю — ліворуч і праворуч
>   — стояли гармати, гармати, гармати... Немов уродилися з землі* (Олесь
>   Гончар, III, 1959, 217).

Доповню, що на Полтавщині вживається ***А(ж) ось і він*** (*вона/він/ми* тощо)! у такому ж значенні. Підтвердження знаходимо в СУМ:

[ОСЬ](http://sum.in.ua/s/osj), част.

> **Аж ось:** а) ***коли раптом; несподівано***. *Сіли за вечерю, аж ось ізнов іде Кирило Тур* (Пантелеймон Куліш, Вибр., 1969, 95)...

Answer (score 0):

Заглянемо в [російсько-український словник](http://stalivyrazy.org.ua/everyfile.php?transfer=folders/te/tut.html) сталих виразів, де дається такий переклад:

Тут і (тут як) уродився, уродилася, уродилося; як тут; (іноді) сусіль.

[Онлайн російсько-український словник](https://translate.academic.ru/%D1%82%D1%83%D1%82+%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA+%D1%82%D1%83%D1%82/ru/uk/) пропонує:

> тут, оту́т; ту́течки, ту́теньки, оту́течки, оту́теньки; (вот здесь)
>   о́сьде, о́сьдечки
>
> тут же — (тотчас) відра́зу [ж], зра́зу [ж]
>
> тут как \тут — в знач. сказ. тут як уроди́вся, тут і вроди́вся

І гадаю хорошим варіантом буде "тут же" із [СУМу](http://sum.in.ua/s/tut).